# Spring integration org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException handling

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms, spring-integration-dsl

I have following spring integration flow:

```
        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow innerInFlow(@Value("${jms.concurrency:10}") String concurrency) {
            return IntegrationFlows
                    .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                            Jms.container(connectionFactory, innerQueue)
                                    .concurrency(concurrency)
                                    .taskExecutor(taskExecutor()).get())
                            .extractPayload(true))
                    .transform(Transformers.deserializer())
                    .route(eventRouter())
                    .get();
        }
```

And after routing

```
        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow findPersonClienFlow(FindClientHandler findClientHandler) {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(findPersonClienChannel())
                    .transform(findClientHandler, "queryToFindClientRequest")
                    .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(connectionFactory).requestDestination(cifRequestQueue)
                            .replyDestination(cifResponseQueue).get())
                    .get();
        }

    }
```

In the `Jms.outboundGateway` I have `org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException` and I cant understand how I can handle this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `MessageTimeoutException` is there because the other side doesn't send you a reply into the `cifResponseQueue`.

You can configure there a `receiveTimeout()`, but it is `5 secs` by default anyway.

Also you can configure a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` or `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` on this `Jms.outboundGateway()` to really handle this exception some specific way, using an `advice(...)` of the `ConsumerEndpointSpec`.

See Docs on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain

**UPDATE**

Also as Gary pointed you can catch an exception from the `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()`  level using its `errorChannel()` and some flow subscribed to this channel.

Comment: Is it really problem? It is framework, it must have tools for this regular problem. Or I dont understand something?

Comment: You can add an `errorChannel` to the `messageDrivenChannelAdapter` and handle the error on a flow from that channel.

Comment: How I can do that?

Comment: The Framework can't make an assumption what really to do with that exception, but it provides for your a plenty of tools to do the right choice in each case.